# How can I add several strings to a List<string> property?

Tags: javascript

I get this error message when I want to add playerrewards to ItemIds. The property ItemIds is List. What is wrong?

> "errorDetails": {
>                 "ItemIds": [
>                   "invalid item at index 0: The ItemIds field is required."
>                 ]
>               }

In this case, I want to add 2 different strings to ItemIds, but sometimes the amount changes and I will need to add a different amount of strings to ItemIds. playerrewards is not always just 2 strings, for example in another case playerrewards could consist of 10 different strings that I need to add to ItemIds.

How can I add playerrewards to the property ItemIds?

```
 var playerrewards = [];
 playerrewards.push("ItemTitaniumSword");
 playerrewards.push("ItemBambooSword");
 var result = server.GrantItemsToUser(
 {
     PlayFabID: currentPlayerId,
     CatalogVersion : "New Shop",
     ItemIds : [playerrewards]
 });
```

Comment: Did you mean `ItemIds : playerrewards` instead of `ItemIds : [playerrewards]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try assigning the value directly as `playerrewards` is a variable now

```
 var playerrewards = [];
 playerrewards.push("ItemTitaniumSword");
 playerrewards.push("ItemBambooSword");
 var result = server.GrantItemsToUser(
 {
   PlayFabID: currentPlayerId,
   CatalogVersion : "New Shop",
   ItemIds : playerrewards
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you trying to store one array inside another one.

```js
{...
ItemIds : [/*playerrewards is [Array]*/]
}
```

As I understand there are two solutions:
First is to store playerrewards  directly, and it will be like this

```js
{...
ItemIds : playerrewards
}
```

Second is to use spread operator, it will bring you a possibility to merge previous state of playerrewards with new one without any extra methods as push and etc.

```js
{...
ItemIds : [...playerrewards]
}
```

What's using better for the task is up to you =)